# IC for 4 Kbytes of RAM

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, memory, ram

Is there a Memory IC for 4Kbytes of RAM? I'm trying to make a schematic capture in Proteus and I need a Memory IC for 4Kbytes of RAM, I've searched throughout the library and I can't find one, tried searching for a 32Kbit one too.. 
It's for an assignment from my lecturer, and he specifically instructed to add 4 Kbytes of external RAM to a AT89C51 Microcontroller.

Comment: Have you asked the google?  Or maybe one of the major chip manufacturers? Also, what kind of connection are you wanting? Parallel? SPI? I2C?

Comment: Does he specifically say "a 4 kbyte RAM chip", or just "4 kbyte of RAM"? If the latter you can use any size bigger than 4 kbyte and only use some of it (tie higher address lines to 0V)

Comment: Well I'm not sure, the instruction to be exact was "Add one external RAM with a capacity of 4Kbyte, installed at address 1000h-1FFFh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky. Most of them would be about 25 years old by now, and capacities mostly went straight from 2 kbytes (e.g HM6116) to 8 kbytes (HM6164)

I'd go for 8 kbytes... Similar parts are *just* still available e.g. [Cypress CY6264](http://uk.farnell.com/cypress-semiconductor/cy6264-70snxc/ic-sram-64k-5v-smd-6264-soic28/dp/8911460) If 8k is not permitted, wire the highest address bit to '0' and keep quiet about it...

Answer (score 0):

[search here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/2556980?k=sram) you can find any component here and related datasheets.